# How can I make Travis CI give me the code coverage and stop build if the coverage isn't the expected

Tags: java, automated-tests, code-coverage, travis-ci

I work using Travis CI in my applications and I have to do code coverage on Travis, but I need stop the build if my code coverage is not working as expected. If I expected a coverage about 15% - unit tests, but report only 5%, I want to stop the build. But I don't have idea if this is possible.

I use Java, Gradle and JaCoCo to do my tests (with JUnit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried configuration from JaCoCo plugin documentation? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_violation_rules